# MotionLayout animation from List to detail

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I'm wondering which method from MotionLayout may help me to re-create this animation the one you see a list of items.

The animation is the same as the image, you tap on an item of the list and the images "makes bigger" until it fits to the detail activity.

Is this necessary MotionLayout? Or it can be done with other ways? Because I've seen ActivityOptionsCompat transitions to do this but perhaps is old.

I've seen SharedElements and perhaps this is what I need but I'd like to see an example of this.

### Note

**Both are Activities (ListActivity --> DetailActivity)**

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this effect.
The best way depends on many things.

For example if the detail page must be an Activity than research "activity transitions"
If it can be all in a single activity then MotionLayout might be the easiest.
What is in the list also plays a role in that decision.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that, it's an Activity navigating to an Activity